# How to use tensor cores instead of cuda cores in my code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, tensor

I have RTX2070 Nvidia graphic card which has tensor cores on it. I want to run my deep learning code utilizing tensor cores instead of Cuda cores. Is it possible in this graphic card? and isn't there any specific driver that I should install in order to do that?
and how should I check to know whether the model is running on tensor cores or Cuda cores?
I am using Keras framework on windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

According to [NVIDIA](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-user-guide/index.html#tensorcore):

> The container enables Tensor Core math by default

If you want to disable it you can set `TF_DISABLE_CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH` to `1`.

Comment: Nvidia has mentioned the Volta and Tesla graphic cards architecture, and it has not mentioned anywhere that their RTX graphic cards support this functionality. However, RTX cards have tensor cores on them too. @carobnodrvo

Comment: @raminkarimian As far as I am aware off, RTX series uses Turing micro-architecture and the article from above mentions `The TensorFlow container includes support Tensor Cores starting in Volta’s architecture...`. Since Turing is newer then Volta, it should work.